# Handle GEOJSON file using ORM in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, hibernate, file, orm

I have a GEOJSON file called abc.json

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -8.5,
                    40.9
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "parameters": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Jethalal",
                    "employeeId": "Jethalal",
                    "category": "account"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.1,
                    41.5
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "parameters": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Atmaram",
                    "employeeId": "Atmaram",
                    "category": "sales"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to know if there is any ORM exist to deal with the **large data** in the GEOJSON file.

Example - I want to update field 'category' to "purchase" of Jethalal. I'll just call an update method.

```
Feature feature = jsonRepository.findById(1);
feature.setCategory("purchase");
jsonRepository.save(feature);
```

And my file will look like

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -8.5,
                    40.9
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "parameters": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "name": "Jethalal",
                    "employeeId": "Jethalal",
                    "category": "purchase"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -9.1,
                    41.5
                ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "parameters": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "name": "Atmaram",
                    "employeeId": "Atmaram",
                    "category": "sales"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I know libraries like

1. Jackson
2. GSON
3. json-simple
   But all these libraries first fetch whole file data in the in the form of object and then allows to perform operations on it.
   I want to do operations without fetching whole file data.

Comment: It would help the community debug if you explained what you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: @AdamB Please have a look on the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate dynamic update to update the JSON fields. Here is the reference.

https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-dynamic-update-json-properties/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).